# Electronic drum kit compatible with Rock Band 4 on Xbox One

Tags: gaming, music, midi

I am looking into getting a electronic drum kit that I can use for both recreational use (like an acoustic drum set) and for Rock Band 4, preferably with pro-cymbal support.

I was thinking about getting an ION drum kit, but I have found [this comment](http://forums.harmonixmusic.com/discussion/comment/5154130#Comment_5154130) amongst others in this thread.

> Q: I play Rock Band with my ION Drum Kit. Will the ION Drum Kit, as well as other MIDI drum kits, be compatible with Rock Band 4?
>
> A: The short answer is “no, not at launch.” Our first priority is to make sure that the core Rock Band legacy instruments be compatible on day one when Rock Band 4 launches – and they will be! If you want to see ION support in Rock Band 4, you can let ION Audio know by contacting them here: http://www.ionaudio.com/support/. We know that many of you play Rock Band using these peripherals, and we are actively working on finding a solution to this compatibility issue.

Is there an alternative to playing an e-kit with Rock Band 4 on Xbox One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to my Guitar Center and talked with one of the drum techs and decided on the [Alesis Crimson Mesh Kit](https://www.alesis.com/crimson-mesh-kit) based on the level of customization provided at the price given. This kit gives me the feel of an acoustic drum set with the added ability to make my own sounds while having room to expand. I noticed that it also has both USB and MIDI outputs so this will help out with either editing my live drum sessions on the computer or plug this setup into an adapter for Rock Band.