# Solution to play an electronic drum kit on Rock Band 4 on Xbox One

Tags: gaming, music, midi

To go into some more detail, I am trying to use an electronic drum set as a drum controller for Rock Band 4 on Xbox One. I have the e-kit I am going to use from [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/939/electronic-drum-kit-compatible-with-rock-band-4-on-xbox-one). This kit has both USB and MIDI out so I should have some flexibility in connecting to some kind of adapter.

Is there an adapter or accessory I can use to connect my e-kit to my Xbox One?

---

**Update**:

Snippets from PR and Communications Lead, Nick Chester:
http://www.popoptiq.com/last-minute-word-harmonix-rock-band-4/

This is stating how there is no official support for ION Rocker drums and the MIDI Pro Adapter.

> I asked two questions about the ION Rocker drums and the MIDI Pro Adapter and Chester’s response to the first was the expected “not at launch” we’ve been hearing, but when I pointed out that the MIDI adapter works on the PS4, he said “The tech just happens to work. That’s great! Fortunately, the PS4 can detect and work with wired USB peripherals.”
>
> He did confirm that the lack of wired instrument compatibility on the Xbox One was a hardware issue in Microsoft’s hands
>
> As for other things that you’ve probably heard a million times with varying levels of calmness, what about electric drums and ION Rockers? Official word so far has been “not at launch,” but is there any news? Any chance Mad Catz has anything in the works in this area?
>
> Chester: No changes here in what we’ve said in the past. We need to launch the core game first and make sure that’s rock solid before thinking about these other things.
>
> From what I’ve seen on the Rock Band sub-Reddit, the Midi Pro Adapter actually works on the PS4 (a Twitch streamer apparently plugged his in and full combo’d “I Bet My Life” with it). Was this intentional or just a happy coincidence from how last-gen instruments work on the console?
>
> Chester: The tech just happens to work. That’s great! Fortunately, the PS4 can detect and work with wired USB peripherals.
>
> Chester: The Xbox One simply doesn’t recognize wired USB controllers or instruments. It’s due to security at the console level and how it recognizes and handles peripherals.

---

Here is a workaround someone posted by using a Guitar Hero: World Tour drum brain and connected an e-kit to it and matched the MIDI settings

Source (very long and ongoing thread): http://forums.harmonixmusic.com/discussion/comment/5189226/#Comment_5189226

> Basically I removed a working brain off a broken GHWT drum set. Then moved the midi port to inside the casing. So now I can connect it to my Roland Kit and use the following MIDI settings to match the GHWT drums. Rockbound will recognize it as a GHWT kit so it will not support Pro-Drum mode BUT you can still set up your cymbals to trigger the correct color similar to what a lot of people did in rock band 2.
>
> Snare (red): 38
> Tom (yellow): 46
> Closed HiHat (yellow): 46
> Open HiHat (blue): 48
> Tom (blue): 48
> Ride (blue): 48
> Tom (green): 45
> Crash (green): 45
> Kick (orange): 36

*I will keep this workaround posted here until someone can implement this and post their answer along with their findings.*

---

**To Sum Up**:

What I am looking for is either some kind of custom made (or official) adapter that can pass the e-kit to the Xbox One directly or a method of using an older RB or GH drum set as a pass-through device (with detailed instructions).

The only **requirement** on top of basic Rock Band drumming functionality is to be compatible with "Pro-Cymbal Mode".

---

**Additional Update**:

Snippet from Harmonix Product Manager, Daniel Sussman:
http://www.harmonixmusic.com/blog/the-future-of-rock-band-4/

This is from the company that made Rock Band 4.

> We know there are a bunch of other things that are important that we are actively working on (Xbox One support for ION drums, for example). Stay tuned for more info, when we have details, trust that we’ll share them.

This next quote is showing what is their highest priority as of December 15, 2015. I am speculating the support for ION drums won't be available till after January.

> We hear everyone clamoring for the export entitlements of previous Rock Band games, so we’re bumping their priority to the top of the list. We’re shooting to have these up in the store for the folks who’ve exported their prior games in January. We’re starting with the original Rock Band and then following up with Rock Band 2 and Lego Rock Band.

---

**Further Update**:

From Harmonix regarding to their dev plans for Rock Band 4. For the case of this question, look at the plans in the Fall with these two links and the picture below.

http://www.harmonixmusic.com/blog/online-ions-and-more-a-pax-east-panel-recap/

http://www.harmonixmusic.com/blog/may-dlc-artists-double-kick-support-and-battleborn-characters-heading-to-rock-band-4/

[image: 2016 Roadmap]

Comment: Well Things should change now since the windows 10 upgrade has been rolling out.
they've announced full mouse compatibilty that'll go hand hand with the exsisting keyboard compatibility. (someone said halo 5 on pc?)
There Chronosmax that's been investigating in the possibilities so you could wait a bit to see if they come out with an adapter ;)

Comment: Here's a DIY solution if you're into that: https://www.reddit.com/r/Rockband/comments/3ml5bo/made_ion_rocker_wireless_so_i_can_play_rock_band_4/

Answer (score 1):

```
 This is a DIY solution,
```

but I am currently working on building e-drum
connectors into a Rockband 4 xbox one drum set. The wireless drums are the drum brain. I so far have it detecting the input from e-drum and e-cymbal. I hope to have the entire set-up working in a week or so.

```
 UPDATE 2/17/21:
```

I have all 4 drum pads working with E-drums plugged in. Cymbals and kickpedal being a problem as they all use 3.5 mm headphone style connectors. Old RB kickpedals and Old RB Cymbals with the 3.5 mm connecters work. 2/18/21 I just tested 3 E-Cymbals at once and they worked perfect. Kickpedal only thing left.

```
 UPDATE 2/22/21:
```

Today I did a test with a game kick pedal but full e drum pads and e cymbals. On Hard difficulty I scored 97% on Ghost of Perdition by Opeth. A pretty difficult song. Frankly the game drum pedal is the weak link but the set performs well. The next step will be to find a way to attach the rb4 drum kit to my drum set frame where the controls are reachable and vibration mitigated.